# Text in the center point of a line in three js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

What I have.

[image: The text here is positioned on top left portion of the browser]

What I want to achieve:

[image: I want to get to this part where there's a space in center of the line for text placement]

So Here's my questions:

1. How do I convert position x and y in three js to browser coordinates so I can position the text correctly in the center of the line? I only added example for vertical lines I'll have different lines like horizontal and diagonal lines.
2. How do I cut the the arrow lines in the center so there's a space for the text?

Here's my code

```js
var gridCanvas = document.getElementById('gridcanvas');
   var ctx = gridCanvas.getContext('2d');
   ctx.beginPath();
   for(var x=0.5; x<gridCanvas.width; x+=20) {
       ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
       ctx.lineTo(x, gridCanvas.height);
   }
   for(var y=0.5; y<gridCanvas.height; y+=20) {
       ctx.moveTo(0, y);
       ctx.lineTo(gridCanvas.width, y);
   }

   ctx.strokeStyle = 'lightgrey';
   ctx.stroke();

   var container = document.getElementById( '3dcontainer' );
   var aspect = 400 / 400;
   var viewHeight = 400;
   var viewWidth = viewHeight * aspect;
   var scene = new THREE.Scene();
   var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
       viewWidth / - 2, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2, viewHeight / - 2, 1, 1000);

   camera.translateZ(15);
   scene.add(camera);

   var points = {
    start : {x: 1.0229999999999109, y: 150.44000000000005},
    end : {x: 1.0229999999999118, y: -151.50399999999996}
   };

   var from = new THREE.Vector3(points.start.x, points.start.y, 0);
   var to = new THREE.Vector3(points.end.x, points.end.y, 0);

   var direction = to.clone().sub(from);
   var length = direction.length();
   
   var hex = 0x0;
   var arrorGroupHelper = new THREE.Group();
   arrorGroupHelper.add(new THREE.ArrowHelper(direction.normalize(), from, length, hex, 5, 5));
   arrorGroupHelper.add(new THREE.ArrowHelper(direction.negate(), to, length, hex, 5, 5));
   scene.add(arrorGroupHelper);

   var threejsCanvas = document.getElementById('threejs-canvas');
   var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas : threejsCanvas,
    alpha : true
   });

   var centerPointLine = findLineCenterPoint(points.start, points.end);
   var text = document.createElement('div');
   text.style.position = 'absolute';
   text.style.zIndex = 5;
   text.innerHTML = length;
   // need to convert this into browser position
   text.style.top = centerPointLine.y + 'px';
   text.style.left = centerPointLine.x + 'px';
   document.getElementById('container').append(text);

   renderer.render( scene, camera );

   function findLineCenterPoint(a, b) {
       return { x: (b.x - a.x) / 2 + a.x, y: (b.y - a.y) / 2 + a.y }; 
   }
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
   #container {
    position: relative;
   }
   #threejs-canvas {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 2;
   }
   #gridcanvas {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/103/three.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
   <canvas id="threejs-canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
   <canvas id="gridcanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with the same code that is used by the `CSS2DRenderer` of `three.js`. Meaning you project the vector into clip space and then convert it so you can use with the CSS `translate` property. If you then apply a white background to your text label, you should achieve your intended result.

```js
var gridCanvas = document.getElementById('gridcanvas');
var ctx = gridCanvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
for(var x=0.5; x<gridCanvas.width; x+=20) {
 ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
 ctx.lineTo(x, gridCanvas.height);
}
for(var y=0.5; y<gridCanvas.height; y+=20) {
 ctx.moveTo(0, y);
 ctx.lineTo(gridCanvas.width, y);
}

ctx.strokeStyle = 'lightgrey';
ctx.stroke();

var container = document.getElementById( '3dcontainer' );
var aspect = 400 / 400;
var viewHeight = 400;
var viewWidth = viewHeight * aspect;
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
 viewWidth / - 2, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2, viewHeight / - 2, 1, 1000);

camera.translateZ(15);
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
scene.add(camera);

var points = {
 start : {x: 1.0229999999999109, y: 150.44000000000005},
 end : {x: 1.0229999999999118, y: -151.50399999999996}
};

var from = new THREE.Vector3(points.start.x, points.start.y, 0);
var to = new THREE.Vector3(points.end.x, points.end.y, 0);

var direction = to.clone().sub(from);
var length = direction.length();

var hex = 0x0;
var arrorGroupHelper = new THREE.Group();
arrorGroupHelper.add(new THREE.ArrowHelper(direction.normalize(), from, length, hex, 5, 5));
arrorGroupHelper.add(new THREE.ArrowHelper(direction.negate(), to, length, hex, 5, 5));
scene.add(arrorGroupHelper);

var threejsCanvas = document.getElementById('threejs-canvas');
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
 canvas : threejsCanvas,
 alpha : true
});

var centerPointLine = findLineCenterPoint(points.start, points.end);
var text = document.createElement('div');
text.style.position = 'absolute';
text.style.zIndex = 5;
text.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
text.innerHTML = length;

var vector = new THREE.Vector3( centerPointLine.x, centerPointLine.y, 0 );
vector.project( camera );
// need to convert this into browser position

var widthHalf = viewWidth / 2;
var heightHalf = viewHeight / 2;

var style = 'translate(-50%,-50%) translate(' + ( vector.x * widthHalf + widthHalf ) + 'px,' + ( - vector.y * heightHalf + heightHalf ) + 'px)';
text.style.transform = style;

document.getElementById('container').append(text);

renderer.render( scene, camera );

function findLineCenterPoint(a, b) {
 return { x: (b.x - a.x) / 2 + a.x, y: (b.y - a.y) / 2 + a.y }; 
}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
#container {
 position: relative;
}
#threejs-canvas {
 position:absolute;
 z-index: 2;
}
#gridcanvas {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
 <canvas id="threejs-canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
 <canvas id="gridcanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

BTW: Consider to directly use [CSS2DRenderer](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/renderers/CSS2DRenderer) which is ideal if you want to render HTML based label connected to 3D objects.

`three.js R112`